# How to format a multi-line list vertically

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij Idea 20, and I'm trying to reformat my code.
When I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>, I want my multiline code (either separated by ',' or '.') to go one under another (vertically).

Example of current code

```
public Response retrieveResults(@QueryParam("record") String record,
@QueryParam("page") @DefaultValue("1") Integer page,@QueryParam("perPage") Integer perPage,
@QueryParam("orderBy") String orderByField,
@QueryParam("orderDirection") @DefaultValue("asc") String orderDirection) {
```

Example of desired code

```
public Response retrieveResults(@QueryParam("record") String record,
                                @QueryParam("page") @DefaultValue("1") Integer page,
                                @QueryParam("perPage") Integer perPage,
                                @QueryParam("orderBy") String orderByField,
                                @QueryParam("orderDirection") @DefaultValue("asc") String orderDirection) {
```

What are the correct settings for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your `code style` settings, so follow the following path in your Intellij IDEA:

`Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `Java` -> `Wrapping and Braces` tab -> `method deceleration parameters` --->

select the ***`wrap always`*** or ***`wrap if long`*** or ***`chop down if long`*** options based on your needs.

You can also check the `Align when multi-line`.

[image]